# Do we have a @beforeTests method which can run once, before all the tests starts

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, junit4, junit3

In Junit, I know there is a @beforeclass  , @before annotation, do we have a annotation or design, 
allow us to write a method to run ONLY once before the whole testing process?

we have a script, which setup some database data (config, static, lookup table etc.....) for the test, but its too expensive to run before each individual test, we would like it to set it, only once before start running any test.

thanks!

Comment: Hi I don't understand what's wrong with [@ BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) db connections is even the example given in the documentation. If you have some base class to your test classes it can be convenient to place the @ BeforeClass there as according to documentation _The @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those the current class._

Comment: Getting a `@BeforeSuite` / `@AfterSuite` annotation is a feature that's often requested, I suggest you email the JUnit mailing-list and mention your interest there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `maven`, I'll go this way: you could use the `pre-integration-test` phase to run this one-time expensive script (symmetrically, you clean up in `post-integration-test`).

You could use exec-maven-plugin for this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>some-execution</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable><!-- runnable command or file name here --></executable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

JUnit does not have this kind of annotation, because it does not make any assumption about the environment: its goal is to test one class at a time in an isolated manner.

Answer (score 1):

[DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html) provides exactly the thing you are looking for. Its a JUnit extension only.

- It has setUp operation options like Clean_Insert - which means the db will be cleaned and required data will be automatically insterted. and many others like Refresh, Update, Insert etc
- Event easier is - In order to use Dbunit you are not required to extend the DBTestCase class. You can override the standard [JUnit setUp()](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html#noextend) method and execute the desired operation on your database.
- database configuration operation
- alot of options on dataset - flat, xml, database , streaming

Comment: I guess DBUnit can run before each test method , or test class. does it support to run ONLY ONCE before all of the tests.if yes, could you make a example please.

Comment: Junit is about setting up test data, testing and cleaning test data PER test. As it is unit testing each test is responsible for setting up the data it needs for testing. And cleaning it after its done testing is Very Important as such data could cause mess, interfere with other test's results and may end up staying there forever.

Comment: Yes it doesn't have a standard way of doing what you need(like an annotation @beforeSuite). But we can get it done as follows, Create 2 testcases. 1) first testcase's setup() - will have the code mentioned in point 2 above. And test that data is populated 2) second testcase is responsible for clearing all test data and test that it has be cleared. Run the first test before all tests and the second after all tests.